# Networkx - How can i get value from "all_pairs_shortest_path_length" function?

Tags: python, networkx

First i have a look at how to use all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length function in [Networkx - How to get shortest path length between nodes showing node id instead of label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834355/networkx-how-to-get-shortest-path-length-between-nodes-showing-node-id-instead) at the first anwser

when i try to get distance value from these code

```
G = nx.read_gpickle("Database/Pickle/man.gpickle")
path_lengths = nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(G, weight='cost')
l = path_lengths.get("Man").get("Year")
print(l)
```

but it error like this

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'get'
```

this is how in `path_lenghts` look like when i print with these code

```
for p in path_lengths:
   print(p)
```

output

```
('Man', {'Man': 0, 'Woman': 1.1532125205930808, 'Year': 1.9607843137254901, 'Baby': 2.4390243902439024})
('Woman', {'Woman': 0, 'Man': 1.1532125205930808, 'Baby': 1.477832512315271, 'Year': 2.4390243902439024})
('Year', {'Year': 0, 'Man': 1.9607843137254901, 'Woman': 2.4390243902439024, 'Baby': 3.9168569025591733})
('Baby', {'Baby': 0, 'Woman': 1.477832512315271, 'Man': 2.4390243902439024, 'Year': 3.9168569025591733})
```

Comment: Your posting is inconsistent: the error message clearly states that the object in question -- a dictionary entry? -- is a generator, but your output indicates some non-Python sequence of tuples that contain a string and a dict.

Comment: thank you for suggestion, now i have add some more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using networkx v2.x.  The code you have written assumes `all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length` is a dict.  This was the case in networkx v1.11 (and probably earlier as well).

However it has now changed.  It now returns an iterator.  Here is information from the [migration guide](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/migration_guide_from_1.x_to_2.0.html):

> With the release of NetworkX 2.0 we are moving to a view/iterator reporting API. We have changed many methods from reporting lists or dicts to iterating over the information.

The simplest change to your code would be to use

```
path_lengths = dict(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(G, weight='cost'))
```

instead of how you currently define `path_lengths`.

Comment: thank you, i get it now but i think it not suitable for very big graph right ? actually now i try to find all pair with given node by using `loop` with `single_source_shortest_path_length` , but i think it takes too long.

Comment: and i tried with `dict(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(G, weight='cost'))` but it takes too long also.

Comment: Yes, it will take a long time.  The problem is that you are finding shortest paths between **all** pairs.  This is slow because there are many pairs.  If you don't need all pairs, there are methods to do just specific pairs.

Answer (score 0):

This is still quite strange.  Your posting is still incomplete, but I think I can identify one of two problems.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

To diagnose the problem more closely, do the basic debugging:

```
print (type(path_lengths), path_lengths)
```

Your print loop masks the problem by pushing the critical variable through an iterator.  The error message claim that you're trying to call the `get` method of a generator.  You have *two* `get` calls in that line, but haven't tried to figure out which is the problem.

**Hypothesis 1**

Although `all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length` is supposed to return a dict, you somehow have a generator.  The `print type` above will check that problem.  If this is the case, you need to convert for your desired usage, such as

```
path_list = list(path_lengths)
```

**Hypothesis 2**

You *did* get a dict returned, but the info therein are not what you think you have.  What you've printed out indicates that you have tuples as your keys.  Look at one line, one `p in path_lengths`:

```
('Man', {'Man': 0,
         'Woman': 1.1532125205930808, 
         'Year': 1.9607843137254901, 
         'Baby': 2.4390243902439024
        }
)
```

This also does not have a `get` method, although your error then would have been

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

---

Either way, I'm highly suspicious of your network set-up; the output indicates that you have unusual values in the network.